# How to get a certain data in the second autocomplete input that depend on what typed in the first input in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, autocomplete

Okay, so I don't know how to properly express my simple problem because of how simple it is, I guess.

Basically, I have an autocomplete done by me in my React project.. I have two inputs "Country" and "City". When I type a country my autocomplete works great giving me suggestions but now I have to make the same for my second input so it would give me a list of cities that depends on which country is typed in the "Country" input...

"United Kingdom" => "London, Birmingham, Bighton etc."

How can I do that? Thank you!

P.S. I already have all the lists of countries and cities, I just don't know how to make the second input to depend on an information in the first one.

**Code here**

Autocomplete.jsx
https://github.com/lembas-cracker/Weather-app/blob/master/src/Autocomplete.jsx

Form.jsx
https://github.com/lembas-cracker/Weather-app/blob/master/src/Form.jsx

Comment: If possible post your code here , so that we can give solution according to that !!

Comment: 1. Make your `Form` component stateful.
2. Add a state property for `countries` in `Form` (let it be `state.countryId`).
3. Pass this property as a prop into the second `Autocomplete`.
4. When the first autocomplete changes, change the `state.countryId` of the `Form`.

All above is shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

> P.S. I already have all the lists of countries and cities, I just don't know how to make the second input to depend on an information in the first one.

If you know which country the city belongs to (perhaps via a key in the city object), you could run a simple `filter` function to remove any cities that don't belong to that country.

```
this.state = {
    selectedCountry: 'London',
};

const cities = [
    { name: "Toronto", country: "Canada" },
    { name: "London", country: "United Kingdom" }
];

const filteredCities = cities.filter(city => {
    return city.country !== this.state.selectedCountry;
});
```

On your city input field make sure to create an `onBlur` function to will run the filter on your cities list once the user leaves that input field.

Answer (score 0):

Made a quick example. Did you mean smth like this? Since you haven't provided any part of your source code, I used plain HTML `select` for the demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/arfeo/n5u2wwjg/204186/

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        countryId: 1,
    };
  }

  onCountryChange(countryId) {
    this.setState({ countryId: parseInt(countryId) });
  }

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <Input
          key="countriesInput"
          type="countries"
          countryId={this.state.countryId}
          onChange={(countryId) => this.onCountryChange(countryId)}
        />
        <Input
          key="citiesInput"
          type="cities"
          countryId={this.state.countryId}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Input extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.selectRef = null;
  }

    renderOptions() {
    const countries = [
        {
        id: 1,
        name: 'England',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Germany',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'France',
      },
    ];

    const cities = [
        {
        countryId: 1,
        cities: [
            {
            id: 1,
            name: 'London',
          },
            {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Liverpool',
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Salisbury'
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        countryId: 2,
        cities: [
            {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Berlin',
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: 'Frankfurt',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        countryId: 3,
        cities: [
            {
            id: 6,
            name: 'Paris',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];

    switch (this.props.type) {
        case 'countries': {
        return countries.map((country) => (
          <option
            key={country.id.toString()}
            value={country.id}
          >
            {country.name}
          </option>
        ));
      }
        case 'cities': {
        const citiesMap = cities.filter((city) => city.countryId === this.props.countryId);

        if (citiesMap && citiesMap[0]) {
            const citiesList = citiesMap[0].cities;

          if (citiesList) {
            return citiesList.map((city) => (
              <option
                key={city.id.toString()}
                value={city.id}
              >
                {city.name}
              </option>
            ));
          }
        }

        return null;
      }
      default: return null;
    }
  }

    render() {
    return (
        <select name={this.props.type} ref={(ref) => this.selectRef = ref} onChange={() => this.props.onChange(this.selectRef.value)}>
        {this.renderOptions()}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

---

**UPDATE**

1. Make your `Form` component stateful.
2. Add a state property for `countries` in `Form` (let it be `countryId`).
3. Pass this property as a prop into the second `Autocomplete` component.
4. When the first `Autocomplete` changes, change the `countryId` of the `Form`.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar which may help you.

The `Object.keys(instutiontypes)` you could use to have an array of countries, instead. Then inside of those values, you can have an array of objects. You could have the cities here, e.g. `{value: "Manchester", "label: Manchester", phoneExt: "0114"}`

```
const instutiontypes =  {
Kindergarten: [
    { value: "PreK", label: "PreK" },
    { value: "K1", label: "K1" },
    { value: "K2", label: "K2" },
    { value: "K3", label: "K3" },
  ],
  "Primary School": [
    { value: "Grade 1", label: "Grade 1" },
    { value: "Grade 2", label: "Grade 2" },
    { value: "Grade 3", label: "Grade 3" },
    { value: "Grade 4", label: "Grade 4" },
    { value: "Grade 5", label: "Grade 5" },
    { value: "Grade 6", label: "Grade 6" },
  ],
}
```

To have the options in my input, I use `Object.keys(instutiontypes)` to get `['Kindergarten','Primary School']`

Then, to get the array of ages to give to my secondary dropdown, I have written this code:

```
const types = ['Selection1', 'Selection2']

  const agesList = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    Object.values(institutionTypes[types[i]]).map(({ label }) =>
      agesList.push(label)
    );
  }
```

This way, the `ages` dropdown list is dependent on the values passed to `institutionTypes`.

I'm using mui's `<Autocomplete />` components to make them be search dropdowns, with the prop `options` for the arrays.